# Android Management API - Single App in Kiosk Mode - How to hide status and navigation bar?

Tags: fullscreen, statusbar, navigationbar, kiosk-mode, android-management-api

### What I would like to achieve?

For internal purposes only / within our enterprise only, I would like to have Android tablets, which run only one single app (made with Ionic/Angular) which even appears after restarting the tablet and the user is not able to leave it.

I think the technical description of what I would like to achieve is called a dedicated devices (formerly called corporate-owned single-use, or COSU).

### How would I like to achieve it?

I would like to achieve this with [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/), which looks like a great choice for a MDM (Mobile Device Management) solution.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/management/policies/dedicated-devices) Google shows how to achieve this with an Android Management API policy.

### The Problem?

I am not able to get rid of the status and navigation bar.

For testing purposes I tried to achieve this with the regular YouTube app. With `"statusBarDisabled": true,` I was able to disable the status bar, so the user can not interact with it, but it is still visible.

And same goes for the navigation bar with

```
"persistentPreferredActivities":[  
   {  
      "receiverActivity":"com.google.android.youtube",
      "actions":[  
         "android.intent.action.MAIN"
      ],
      "categories":[  
         "android.intent.category.HOME",
         "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
      ]
   }
]
```

I was able to hide the home and recents buttons, but the back button is still there and the whole navigation bar is visible.

---

The following image visualises the problem:

[image: Shows the YouTube app in kiosk mode, status bar and navigation bar are visible.]

Anyone an idea how I can get rid of the status and navigation bar completely?

---

This is how my whole policy looks like:

```
import json

policy_name = enterprise_name + '/policies/policy1'

policy_json = '''
{
"safeBootDisabled": true,
"statusBarDisabled": true,
"keyguardDisabled": true,
"screenCaptureDisabled": true,
"factoryResetDisabled": true,
"cameraDisabled": true,
"blockApplicationsEnabled": true,
"systemUpdate": {
"type": "WINDOWED",
"startMinutes": 120,
"endMinutes": 240
},

"policyEnforcementRules": [{
"settingName": "persistentPreferredActivities",
"blockAction": {
"blockAfterDays": 0
},
"wipeAction": {
"wipeAfterDays": 3,
"preserveFrp": true
}
}],

"applications": [
{
"packageName": "com.google.android.youtube",
"installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
"lockTaskAllowed": true,
"defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
}
],
"persistentPreferredActivities": [
{
"receiverActivity": "com.google.android.youtube",
"actions": [
"android.intent.action.MAIN"
],
"categories": [
"android.intent.category.HOME",
"android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
]
}
]
}
'''

androidmanagement.enterprises().policies().patch(
name=policy_name,
body=json.loads(policy_json)
).execute()
```

Comment: I guess not that many people using Android Management API. . .

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I'm having the same problem with the new installType KIOSK configuration.

Comment: Same here. And the weird thing for me is that, it actually was working for me last week but it suddenly stopped working when I tried to re-provision the device today with the same policy and app.
And with `kioskCustomLauncherEnabled`, I am able to hide those navigation buttons (but I would prefer `KIOSK` `installType` if possible)

Comment: @H.T.Koo How are you able to hide these buttons?

Answer (score -1):

The two bars you've highlight are actually part of the youtube app NOT part of the android OS/UI. So you can't hide those using the device management API.

Comment: Hey @flint, thanks for your answer. But they are definitely not part of YouTube. The YouTube app itself e.g. has no bar at the bottom with just a back button nor and empty grey bar at the top. But we just handled it within the app instead with the API.